# How to sign a request for Image upload to Amazon S3 in javascript

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services

I have been following railscast #383 which involves a web app that uploads an image to an amazon bucket - this all works fine. I would like to upload to S3 via a remote javascript client.

My approach has been to effectively turn this

```
<%= direct_upload_form_for @uploader do |f| %>
  <p><%= f.file_field :image %></p>
  <p><%= f.submit "Upload Image" %></p>
<% end %>
```

into the following on the remote client which is basic angularjs. So now I have the same form declarations and values now for the remote client.

```
    var f = document.createElement("form");
    f.setAttribute('method',"post");
    f.setAttribute('accept-charset',"UTF-8");
    f.setAttribute('action',"https://acme.s3.amazonaws.com/");
    f.setAttribute('enctype',"multipart/form-data");


    var i = document.createElement("input"); //input element, text
    i.setAttribute('type',"hidden");
    i.setAttribute('name',"utf8");
    i.value = "&#x2713;";

            etc...
```

What I'm not clear on is how to sign the request - on the server-side upload page I have this form tag (below) that set a new value per request. How would I generate this signature value? If the server sends back the generated key via ajax to a different origin I can see this failing ( thus far I've manually transplanted the value which gives an Invalid Sig error from AWS )

```
<input id="image_uploader_signature" name="signature" type="hidden" value="P9xM0CndpfvkSaXXXXXyrVSAE=" />
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to have a look at two possible solutions :

The first one is about generating on the server side pre-signed URL that you can use from the client side to upload objects to a private S3 bucket.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html

If server side pre-generation is not an option for you, you might consider to use the client side JavaScript AWS SDK : http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforbrowser/ 
In particular, the `getSignedURL` method of the S3 object : http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property

--Seb